# Событие клика для накладывающихся элементов

Tags: javascript, css

Есть картинка, над которой абсолютом расположен блок с текстом. По клику на картинку срабатывает js.

Как сделать так, чтобы клик в любую область картинки вызывал срабатывание скрипта – в том числе, когда клик приходится на надпись, перекрывающую картинку?

Comment: *По клику на картинку работает js* - так у вас уже по клику на картинку (в любое место картинки) - вызывает срабатывание скрипта. Код покажите какой то или детальнее объясните что к чему. Или картинка у вас это не файл изображения?)

Comment: картинка у меня обычный `<`img..` , поверх и поперек которой есть надпись , задана другим блоком `<div>` . И в области где в разметке находится эта самая надпись , соответственно и не работает клик по картинке, т.к. тут уже идет клик по блоку с надписью

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Клик нужно делать не на картинку, а на контейнер в котором находиться и картинка и блок с абсолютным позиционированием, и будет вам счастье )

```
<div class="image-container">
<div class="position-absolute">Bla bla bla</div>
<img src="/image.jpg" alt="" title="">
</div>

$('.image-container').on('click', function(){
//Действия по нажатию на картинку
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Ставьте событие клика и на фразу (не очень разумно только); 
Вставьте надпись на картинку в редакторе.

Comment: я думаю я просто сделаю отдельный блок, в который запихну и картинку и фразу, и обработчик js привязать к родителю. А вот надпись нужна как раз отдельно от картинки, так как на стороне формируется массив для разных языков

Answer (score 0):

http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events ​​​​​​​​​​

```
pointer-events: none;
```

Answer (score 0):

callback для клика по координатам элементов, запустите код кликните по надписи или любой из картинок и вне их

```js
$(function() {
  var imgs = $(".block");

  function fn() {
    alert(this.id)
  }

  $(window).click(function(event) {
    imgs.each(function(indx, elem) {
      var pos = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
      var top = event.pageY - window.pageYOffset;
      var left = event.pageX - window.pageXOffset;
      if (pos.top <= top && pos.bottom >= top && pos.left <= left && pos.right >= left) fn.call(elem)
    })
  })
});
```

```css
img {
  margin-top: 100px;
  border: dotted 2px #8B4513;
}
.hot {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://www.stephenleefischer.com/img/thumbs/stackoverflow.jpg" alt="" class="block" id="first">
<svg height="45" width="200" class="hot">
  <text class="status" x="20" y="35" fill="#0000FF">Stack Overflow на русском</text>
</svg>
<img src="http://www.stephenleefischer.com/img/thumbs/stackoverflow.jpg" alt="" class="block" id="test">
```